# ¿Por qué no funcionan las rutas cuando consulto por medio de https?

Tags: nodejs, http, angular5, https, postman

Estoy haciendo una aplicación para manejar una pequeña tienda. El `front end` lo estoy haciendo en angular. El `back end` lo hice en `Node.js`. Le he implementado tanto al`angular` como al `nodejs` `SSL` para que la communication sea segura.

Pero cuando ejecuto el `angular` para que vaya al nodejs y traiga todos los datos, sucede esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No reconoce ninguna de las rutas. Y no da mas información sobre el error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Algo curioso es que todo funciona correctamente si lo hago por medio de http.

He usado `Postman` y aqui todo funciona de maravailla, luego de haber deshabilitado esta opcion:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi es como me aparece la pagina web:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna sugerencia de como pueda solucionar este error? ¿Tendré que deshabilitar alguna configuración en google chrome?

Comment: El certificado SSL va en tu dominio

Comment: He editado la pregunta para que veas como aparece el SSL en angular.

Comment: Ademas, el SSL que estoy usando es un certificado auto firmado.